# Growing eXist database

Tags: orbeon, xforms, exist-db

I'm using Orbeon Forms, and eXist to store filled forms there. And I have next problem, eXist is growing more than 500 MB per day. If I will made reserve copy of whole database, then will delete all DB files, and restore reserved copy, then DB is only 1 GB large, but after few days it becomes 4 GB, and grows, grows and grows...

First I was using embeded eXist 1.2.6, and I thought that it's unstable version, so I moved all data to external eXist 1.4.1, but still it continue to grow in new version.

Here's conf.xml from exist/WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<exist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema/conf.xsd">
    <cluster dbaPassword="" dbaUser="admin" exclude="/db/system,/db/system/config" 
    journalDir="data/journal" 
    protocol="UDP(mcast_addr=228.1.2.3;mcast_port=45566;ip_ttl=8;ip_mcast=true;mcast_send_buf_size=800000;mcast_recv_buf_size=150000;ucast_send_buf_size=800000;ucast_recv_buf_size=150000;loopback=true):PING(timeout=2000;num_initial_members=3;up_thread=true;down_thread=true):MERGE2(min_interval=10000;max_interval=20000):FD(shun=true;up_thread=true;down_thread=true;timeout=2500;max_tries=5):VERIFY_SUSPECT(timeout=3000;num_msgs=3;up_thread=true;down_thread=true):pbcast.NAKACK(gc_lag=50;retransmit_timeout=300,600,1200,2400,4800;max_xmit_size=8192;up_thread=true;down_thread=true):UNICAST(timeout=300,600,1200,2400,4800;window_size=100;min_threshold=10;down_thread=true):pbcast.STABLE(desired_avg_gossip=20000;up_thread=true;down_thread=true):FRAG(frag_size=8192;down_thread=true;up_thread=true):pbcast.GMS(join_timeout=5000;join_retry_timeout=2000;shun=true;print_local_addr=true)"/>


    <db-connection cacheSize="200M" collectionCache="200M" database="native" files="/opt/alfresco-3.4.c/tomcat/work/exist/data/" pageSize="4096">

        <recovery enabled="yes" group-commit="no" journal-dir="/opt/alfresco-3.4.c/tomcat/work/exist/recovery-data/" size="100M" sync-on-commit="yes" force-restart="yes" consistency-check="yes"/>

        <watchdog output-size-limit="10000" query-timeout="180000"/>

    </db-connection>

    <indexer caseSensitive="yes" index-depth="5" preserve-whitespace-mixed-content="yes" stemming="no" suppress-whitespace="none" tokenizer="org.exist.storage.analysis.SimpleTokenizer" track-term-freq="yes">

            <modules>
            <module id="ngram-index" file="ngram.dbx" n="3" class="org.exist.indexing.ngram.NGramIndex"/>

            <module id="lucene-index" buffer="32" class="org.exist.indexing.lucene.LuceneIndex"/>
        </modules>

        <stopwords file="stopword"/>

        <index>
            <fulltext attributes="false" default="none">
                <exclude path="/auth"/>
            </fulltext>
        </index>
    </indexer>

    <scheduler>

    </scheduler>
    <serializer add-exist-id="none" compress-output="no" enable-xinclude="yes" enable-xsl="no" indent="yes" match-tagging-attributes="no" match-tagging-elements="no">
    </serializer>

    <transformer class="org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl" caching="yes"/>

    <validation mode="no">
        <entity-resolver>
            <catalog uri="${WEBAPP_HOME}/WEB-INF/catalog.xml"/>
        </entity-resolver>
    </validation>

    <xquery enable-java-binding="no" disable-deprecated-functions="no" enable-query-rewriting="yes" backwardCompatible="no" raise-error-on-failed-retrieval="no">
        <builtin-modules>
            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/lucene" class="org.exist.xquery.modules.lucene.LuceneModule"/>          
            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/ngram" class="org.exist.xquery.modules.ngram.NGramModule"/>

            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/examples" class="org.exist.xquery.modules.example.ExampleModule"/>           
            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/request" class="org.exist.xquery.functions.request.RequestModule"/>            
            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/response" class="org.exist.xquery.functions.response.ResponseModule"/>            
            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/session" class="org.exist.xquery.functions.session.SessionModule"/>            
            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/system" class="org.exist.xquery.functions.system.SystemModule"/>
            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/text" class="org.exist.xquery.functions.text.TextModule"/>           
            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/transform" class="org.exist.xquery.functions.transform.TransformModule"/>            
            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/util" class="org.exist.xquery.functions.util.UtilModule"/>            
            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/validation" class="org.exist.xquery.functions.validation.ValidationModule"/>           
            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xmldb" class="org.exist.xquery.functions.xmldb.XMLDBModule"/>            

            <module uri="http://expath.org/ns/http-client" class="org.expath.exist.HttpClientModule"/>        
            <module uri="http://www.expath.org/mod/http-client" src="resource:org/expath/www/mod/http-client/http-client.xqm"/>      

            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/httpclient" class="org.exist.xquery.modules.httpclient.HTTPClientModule"/>

            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/kwic" src="resource:org/exist/xquery/lib/kwic.xql"/>

            <module uri="http://www.json.org" src="resource:org/exist/xquery/lib/json.xq"/>

            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/sequences" src="resource:org/exist/xquery/lib/sequences.xq"/>

            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/versioning" src="resource:org/exist/versioning/xquery/versioning.xqm"/>

            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/testing" src="resource:org/exist/xquery/lib/test.xq"/>   

            <module uri="http://xproc.net/xproc" src="resource:net/xproc/xprocxq/src/xquery/xproc.xqm"/>         
            <module uri="http://xproc.net/xproc/const" src="resource:net/xproc/xprocxq/src/xquery/const.xqm"/>          
            <module uri="http://xproc.net/xproc/ext" src="resource:net/xproc/xprocxq/src/xquery/ext.xqm"/>    
            <module uri="http://xproc.net/xproc/functions" src="resource:net/xproc/xprocxq/src/xquery/functions.xqm"/>        
            <module uri="http://xproc.net/xproc/naming" src="resource:net/xproc/xprocxq/src/xquery/naming.xqm"/>
            <module uri="http://xproc.net/xproc/opt" src="resource:net/xproc/xprocxq/src/xquery/opt.xqm"/> 
            <module uri="http://xproc.net/xproc/std" src="resource:net/xproc/xprocxq/src/xquery/std.xqm"/>     
            <module uri="http://xproc.net/xproc/util" src="resource:net/xproc/xprocxq/src/xquery/util.xqm"/>       

            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/file" class="org.exist.xquery.modules.file.FileModule"/>

            <module uri="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xqdoc" class="org.exist.xqdoc.xquery.XQDocModule"/>

        </builtin-modules>
    </xquery>
    <xupdate allowed-fragmentation="5" enable-consistency-checks="no"/>

</exist>
```

Is it a common problem?
Or may be I configured eXist wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As suggested by @jeowiz, you might want to ask this question in the exit-open mailing list, but growing by 500 MB per day sounds like a lot: about how many new forms get filled per day on that system? And which version of Orbeon Forms are you using? I am asking, because if you're on 3.8, eXist is also used for caching, which might explain the issue you're seeing. In that case, I'd recommend you update to 3.9, which uses Ehcache.

Comment: Yes you're right, I'm using 3.8 version. So updating to 3.9 is the only way? Can't orbeon be configured to use another cache?

Comment: Sorry, the ability to use Ehcache just wasn't there in 3.8. And in 3.9, we just switched to Ehcache, as there were really no downsides to using Ehcache for caching instead of eXist. So I am afraid there is no workaround to updating to 3.9.

Comment: Now, if in 3.8 you are using eXist both to store form data and caching, and want to check that it is the caching that's causing the problem, you can setup Form Runner to use an external eXist, by setting the `oxf.fr.persistence.service.exist.uri` property to point to an external eXist, as I imagine you did, and leaving the embedded eXist used for the cache. Once you verified that it is really the embedded eXist used just for caching that is growing, you'll most likely feel more confident that it is worth the effort to upgrade to 3.9.

Comment: Yes you're right, folder for embeded eXist began to grow for 1Mb per 5 seconds. But I think, I can use this as workaround, at night tomcat stops to make backup of all data, during this time I can delete all files from embeded DB, while necessary data will be safe in external eXist, it's pretty dirty of course, and temporary solution. As soon as I will have time enough I will update orbeon to 3.9

Comment: Yes, if you're stopping Tomcat every day anyway, deleting the whole database at every restart (that is: simply deleting the files in `exist-data`) seems like a good workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @joewiz and @avernet

Now I can answer my own question. The main problem is that I'm using orbeon 3.8, which use eXist DB to store cache there. Updating to 3.9 version will help, because 3.9 use Ehcahe instead.

As temporary workaround, I configured orbeon 3.8 to store data to external eXist for that in **properties-local.xml** I add

```
<property as="xs:anyURI"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.service.exist.uri" value="http://127.0.0.1:8080/exist/rest/db"/>
```

property as told [here](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/exist-configuration#TOC-Configuring-Form-Runner), and embeded eXist to store cache for that next properties should be set

```
<property as="xs:anyURI"  name="oxf.xforms.store.application.uri"                   value="xmldb:exist:///"/>                      
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.xforms.store.application.collection"            value="/db/orbeon/xforms/cache/"/>
```

So when servlet container stops I can safely delete embeded eXist data files.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest asking your question on exist-open, where most eXist developers and users reside.  Subscribe at https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/exist-open -- you won't be sorry.  Good luck!