# eXist db files (words.dbx and dom.dbx) keep increasing in size, how do I reduce them?

Tags: orbeon, exist-db

We are using Orbeon forms 3.7.1 which uses the eXist database 1.2.4. The problem we are hitting is that the .dbx files keep increasing in size even after the sessions have expired.

Specifically the words.dbx and dom.dbx. The only way (I know) to clear them out is to restart Orbeon.

This question is similar to [Growing eXist database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071135/growing-exist-database) but we are using Orbeon 3.7 and we don't have time to upgrade to 3.8 at the moment.

So my question is: How do I reduce the size of those files without restarting Orbeon? Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't think there is a way around this with Orbeon Forms 3.7, which back then was using eXist to store caching information. Hopefully, since 3.7 is now more than 3 years old, and your application held for all that time, it should be able to hold a bit longer, enough to give you the time to upgrade to 3.9 or 4.0, which is just around the corner.